# How to fix dictionary not counting duplicate numbers as new entries

Tags: python, dictionary

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
max_length = 3

squares = {}

while len(squares) < max_length:
    print("Enter the side length of the square:")
    side = input()
    side = int(side)
    Perimeter = side*4
    Area = side*side

    squares[Area] = Perimeter
```

And the problem with this is that when you enter the same side length multiple times, it does not count it as a new entry, and instead keeps asking until unique side lengths are entered. Why is this and how can I fix it?
If this is not possible with dictionaries, is there any alternative ways of doing this so it does allow duplicate keys and then can be converted to a DataFrame for plotting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to make a counter in the while loop that tracks how many inputs the user gives.  Dictionaries don't allow for duplicate entries, so every time you reference a key that is already in the dictionary, you will just overwrite the current value.

ex.

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['key1'] = 'value1'
dictionary['key2'] = 'value2'
print(dictionary.items())  
>> dict_items([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])
```

now, given the same dictionary, we are going to call the same key:
dictionary = {}

```
dictionary['key1'] = 'value1'
dictionary['key2'] = 'value2'
dictionary['key1'] = 'value3'
print(dictionary.items())  
>> dict_items([('key1', 'value3'), ('key2', 'value2')])
```

So, as you can see you are just overwriting the value that corresponds to the key.
If you want to have your loop stop after 3 inputs, just do something like this:

```
max_length = 3

squares = {}
number_of_inputs = 0
while number_of_inputs < max_length:
    print("Enter the side length of the square:")
    side = int(input(...))
    
    Perimeter = side*4
    Area = side*side

    squares[Area] = Perimeter
    number_of_inputs += 1
```

Otherwise, you are going to need to check if the key already exists and handle the situation from there - not sure your end goal so cant help with that.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it from overwriting the key, and if not, what would be better to use for something like this that can then be converted into a dataframe?

Comment: The other answer in this thread is a good solution to not allowing the overwriting of the key.  You could just create an empty dataframe and populate it directly rather than storing it in a dictionary and converting it.  Otherwise, I'm not sure why you would want to prevent the key-value from being overwritten as the dictionary is meant to only have a single key for particular values.  You could store a list with that particular key and just append to the list each time the same key is passed!

Answer (score 1):

This happen because in `dictionary` it's doesn't allow duplicates keys key should be unique and have one value.

- To solve this

```py
max_length = 3

    squares = {}

    while len(squares) < max_length:
        side = input("Enter the side length of the square:")
        side = int(side)
        Perimeter = side * 4
        Area = side * side
        if Area in squares.keys():
            print(f"this is side already exist {side} chose differ one")
        else:
            squares[Area] = Perimeter
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by using a list instead and then using list.append to add new values. Like so

```
max_length = 3
inputs = 0
squares = []

while inputs < max_length:
    print("Enter the side length of the square:")
    side = input()
    side = int(side)
    Perimeter = side*4
    Area = side*side
    inputs = inputs+1

    squares.append([Perimeter, Area])
print(squares)
```

This works for what I'm doing so hopefully this might help others